# Install of Iron Router for Meteor 1.0.2.1 just does not work

Tags: meteor, iron-router

So I've done the todo and leaderboard tutorials and now am excited to begin routing - seems like iron router is the way to go so I install it to my project using

mrt add iron-router

Seems to install ok so I start meteor and navigate to localhost:3000 and my console lights up with:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
helpers.js:141 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
router.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
global-imports.js?784bc180a149e4c10dff977a7f114df67d9952c6:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined
template.tutorialexample.js?e119ff8df948cfe8167f49eb28794995a594841c:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
tutorialexample.js?a4ef596255404350be2cc45303caea02f934cd17:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined

Mind you this is a default app, haven't touched a thing.

So if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I did read somewhere that I should be using 0.8.2 version of iron router - and I then did change my smart.json file to contain:

```
{
  "packages": {
    "iron-router": "0.8.2"
  }
}
```

and then did meteor update etc but still no luck. So any help anyone could provide would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor has changed quite a bit & the instructions/tutorial you've been following is a bit dated.

Previously `mrt` was part of the meteorite packaging system, from Meteor 0.9.0 it has been integrated directly into meteor.

So now you do:

```
meteor add iron:router
```

To add it to your project. Once you start your app up it should present a basic template on how to use it.